# How do I upload a file to firebase storage so that it can be downloaded through the console?

Tags: firebase

I'm having trouble downloading files from firebase storage through the firebase console that I uploaded through the Nodejs Admin SDK. I can upload files successfully and I see them in the firebase storage in the firebase console, but when I click on any of the files the Name field is not a link and there is no way to download the file. If I upload the same file using the Flutter Firebase libraries or using the firebase console UI then I can download it by clicking on the file and then clicking on the Name field, which is a link. I don't see any difference in the files I uploaded through the console UI (that are downloadable) and the ones I uploaded through the NodeJS Admin SDK. Does anyone know what you need to do when uploading a file so that you can download it through the console UI?

I'm trying to upload zipped PB files that have names like: FILE-1.pb.zip, and have Content Type: application/x-zip-compressed

This is my upload code:

```
/**
 * Store file at specified path in cloud storage, default bucket. If there is already a file
 * at destination it is overwritten.
 * @param {String} filePath - path of file to store
 * @param {String} destination - path to store file at in cloud storage
 * @param {String} contentType - mime type of file.
 * @param {String} bucket - OPTIONAL: if specified upload to this bucket instead of default bucket.
 */
async function storeFile(filePath, destination, contentType, bucketName) {
  bucketName = bucketName || globals.firebase.storageBucket;
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(bucketName);
  try {
    // Ref: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#request_properties_JSON
    const options = {
      destination,
      metadata: {
        contentType
      }
    };
    await bucket.upload(filePath, options);
    console.log(`Successfully copied ${filePath} to ${destination} in ${bucketName}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to upload file ${filePath} to ${destination} with error: `, error);
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I examined files uploaded through the console UI and the nodejs admin sdk, and the only difference is that the console uploaded ones have a firebaseStorageDownloadTokens field populated on their metadata.metadata object. I looked into it and that field can be populated when the web library is used, by calling getDownloadURL() (ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files, https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues/34). I don't see anyway to have this field populated using the nodejs admin sdk though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a firebase support ticket and they solved the problem by providing a script to run that can set a download URL on each file. Their response:

> Admin SDK and gsutil, they skip adding some metadata leading to
> different errors while trying to use the Client SDK. This behavior is
> a known issue and our engineering team is already working on it, but
> we don’t have any ETA or timeline. You can add this metadata manually
> or programmatically:
>
> As you can see, if you click on Create new access token and reload the page, the preview is generated.
>
> To do it programmatically you can use [this script](https://gist.github.com/torresalmonte/7bd888ff0b27fd741faf29d473ecb079).